# how to find replacement of deprecated function in scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

For example, this `threshold` function is deprecated according to the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.threshold.html#scipy.stats.threshold).

However, the doc didn't say about any replacement. Is it just gone in the future, or there is already a replacement? If so, How to find the replacement function?

Comment: As the documentation mentions just use `numpy.clip()` - here's the conversation on the [`scipy` list](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-dev/2015-July/020844.html)

Comment: @AChampion Thank you! But it seems to me that numpy.clip is different. For example, how to make small number zero? numpy.clip only clip to interval edges

Comment: If you have an array `a`, then `a[a < cutoff] = 0` will make all elements of `a` smaller than `cutoff` equal to zero.

Comment: @σηγ Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took a bit of digging, but here's the code for `threshold` (`scipy/stats/mstats_basic.py`):

```
def threshold(a, threshmin=None, threshmax=None, newval=0):
    a = ma.array(a, copy=True)
    mask = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=bool)
    if threshmin is not None:
        mask |= (a < threshmin).filled(False)

    if threshmax is not None:
        mask |= (a > threshmax).filled(False)

    a[mask] = newval
    return a
```

But before that I found that, I reverse engineered it from the documentation:

Example array from the docs:

```
In [152]: a = np.array([9, 9, 6, 3, 1, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8])
In [153]: stats.threshold(a, threshmin=2, threshmax=8, newval=-1)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: `threshold` is deprecated!
stats.threshold is deprecated in scipy 0.17.0
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[153]: array([-1, -1,  6,  3, -1,  6, -1, -1, -1,  8])
```

The suggested replacement

```
In [154]: np.clip(a,2,8)
Out[154]: array([8, 8, 6, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2, 2, 8])
....
```

Clipping to  the max or min makes sense; threshold, on the other hand, turns all  out-of-bounds values into some other value such as 0 or -1.  Doesn't sound so useful.  But it's not hard to achieve:

```
In [156]: mask = (a<2)|(a>8)
In [157]: mask
Out[157]: array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
In [158]: a1 = a.copy()
In [159]: a1[mask] = -1
In [160]: a1
Out[160]: array([-1, -1,  6,  3, -1,  6, -1, -1, -1,  8])
```

This is essentially the same as the code I quoted, differing only in how it handles the `None` case for the min or max.

Comment: Thank you. So it seems that np.clip is not a direct replacement of `threshold`

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, np.clip is a direct replacement of threshold, if used properly:

```
np.clip(array-threshold,0,1)
```